# Integrating Git into my workflow

Tags: git, ide, gitlab, tortoisegit, phped

I use NuSphere's PhpED's PHP IDE to crate and debuge PHP script.

I've never used a repository systems, but wish to do so now, and am struggling on how to implement it into my workflow.

I have the following three machines:

Windows 7 PC

- NuShere PhpED IDE (It is set up to use my Local Development Centos Server)
- TortoiseGit
- SourceTree (Not sure if I will use since it doesn't integrate with PhpED)

Local Development Centos Server

- Apache (used with PhpED on Windows PC)
- GitLab
- Samba (not set up yet, but plan on using to share `/var/www` files with PhpED on Windows PC)

Remote Production Centos Server

- Apache

Will I need to install Git on the Windows PC?

Will I need to install Git on the Remote Production Centos Server?

PhpED has some basic shell integration with TortoiseGit. Think it is worth using, or am I better off using some other tool to interface with Git?

Any other description of a recommended workflow would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Will I need to install Git on the Windows PC?

Yes, if you want to `git clone` the repos from your Local Dev Centos server onto your computer

> - Will I need to install Git on the Remote Production Centos Server?

Yes, if you want to push your repos to bares repos on your Remote Production Centos server.
But you can also consider other means to deploy those same repo:
A `post-receive` hook on the local Prod Centos server can:

- checkout those repo (still on the local Prod server, where git is installed anyway), as described for instance in "[Getting GitHub files (and updates) onto an Ubuntu web server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22576537/6309)",
- rsynch that working tree to the prod server (that way, no need for Git on the remote prod server)

Comment: Thanks Von.  If I am using Samba to map the Linux drive to Windows, then will Git not be required on Windows?

Comment: @user1032531 it would still be required, if you want to add, commit, revert, merge or do any of the git commands in the repo you would access through the share. Plus this is really *not* the way to wrok with a *distributed* VCS: you clone on your local computer a repo in order to have the full history *locally*, without depending on the network or on a share.

Comment: The Local Development Centos Server is located in my house, and is on a high speed LAN.  If I have the code on my Windows PC, I would need to keep it synchronized.  Why not make it one drive shared by both?

Comment: @user1032531 Because in that case, you simply don't need git. If you are using git (for versioning and branching), then you clone a repo, you don't access through the network, however fast it is: Git has been designed to be *fast* on the *local* drive, not on the LAN/WAN.

Comment: Thanks again Von.  Do you know of any whitepaper/blog/etc which describes the desired workflow?  There are a bunch of tutorials on setting it up, but I haven't found one describing preferred workflow.

Comment: @user1032531 not really: once GitLab is working, you just clone the repo and start working on it locally. So the main point is to get GitLab up and running, following the doc at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/README.md